# proper way to name a variable already used?

Tags: python, conventions, convention

in python (3.3.3), what is the proper way to name a variable that is already being used?

for example, I want to create the variable `input`. obviously this will not work as there is a python keyword called `input`.

assuming I needed a name similar to `input`, what is the proper way to name it without deviating much from the word `input`, that is, not using a name like `user_input` or `answer`?

Comment: Why not prefix it with an underscore `_`?

Comment: `input` is simply a bad variable name. Be more descriptive.

Comment: @VivekPradhan : Because prefixing with an underscore is conventionally used as a weak "internal use" indicator. See [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles). So using an underscore as a suffix is better for this use case, although as JimStewart said, a more descriptive variable name would be better.

Comment: @PM2Ring, I get your point, thanks for the source. It was helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any name even if it is used by a function.
What you can't is use keywords like `def`, `class`, `if`, `else`...

But of course it is not a good practice to replace those names used by functions to avoid confusion.

A known practice is to add a `_` to the end: `input_`, `class_`...